# Occasional crash when saving core data: Crashed: com.apple.uikit.backgroundTaskAssertionQueue

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm receiving a crash report when saving data to Core Data. However, I can't reproduce it so it only happens occasionally. I'm having trouble figuring out what's wrong with my code.

I have two classes `MyCoreDataManager` and `CoreDataHelper`. On init, I load the persistent container and then create and hold a strong reference to a background context. I call `saveMyData(_:completion:)` whenever I want to save something to Core Data. This creates a `ManagedMyData` object and then saves the context:

```
class MyCoreDataManager {
  private var backgroundContext: NSManagedObjectContext?
  private var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer?
  private var coreDataHelper: CoreDataHelper

  init(coreDataHelper: CoreDataHelper = CoreDataHelper()) {
    self.coreDataHelper = coreDataHelper
    // First load persistent container
    let persistentContainer = NSPersistentContainer(
      name: Self.modelName,
      managedObjectModel: Self.managedObject
    )

    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
    dispatchGroup.enter()
    var containerError: Error?
    persistentContainer.loadPersistentStores { _, error in
      containerError = error
      dispatchGroup.leave()
    }
    dispatchGroup.wait()
    guard containerError == nil else {
      return
    }

    self.persistentContainer = persistentContainer

    // Then load background and main context
    let backgroundContext = persistentContainer.newBackgroundContext()
    backgroundContext.mergePolicy = NSMergePolicy.mergeByPropertyObjectTrump
    self.backgroundContext = backgroundContext
  }

  func saveMyData(
    _ myData: MyData,
    completion: ((ManagedMyData) -> Void)? = nil
  ) {
    guard let backgroundContext = backgroundContext else {
      completion?()
      return
    }
    if persistentContainer == nil {
      completion?()
      return
    }

    backgroundContext.perform { [weak self] in
      guard let self = self else {
        return
      }
      let parameterData = try? JSONEncoder().encode(myData.parameters)
      guard let managedMyData = ManagedMyData(
        context: backgroundContext,
        id: myData.id,
        createdAt: myData.createdAt,
        name: myData.name,
        parameters: parameterData ?? Data()
      ) else {
        return
      }

      self.coreDataHelper.saveContext(backgroundContext) {
        completion?(managedMyData)
      }
    }
  }
}

class CoreDataHelper {
  func saveContext(
    _ context: NSManagedObjectContext,
    completion: (() -> Void)? = nil
  ) {
    context.perform {
      do {
        try context.save() // Crashes here!
        completion?()
      } catch {
        print(error)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The crash that I get is the following:

```
Crashed: com.apple.uikit.backgroundTaskAssertionQueue
0  libxpc.dylib                   0x32334 _xpc_connection_release_message.cold.1 + 64
1  libxpc.dylib                   0xe8a0 _xpc_connection_release_message + 260
2  libxpc.dylib                   0xdf50 xpc_connection_send_message_with_reply_sync + 308
3  RunningBoardServices           0xad2c -[RBSXPCMessage sendToConnection:error:] + 416
4  RunningBoardServices           0x1194c -[RBSXPCMessage invokeOnConnection:withReturnCollectionClass:entryClass:error:] + 104
5  RunningBoardServices           0x3de0 -[RBSXPCMessage invokeOnConnection:withReturnClass:error:] + 32
6  RunningBoardServices           0x1acd4 -[RBSConnection acquireAssertion:error:] + 364
7  RunningBoardServices           0x24b7c -[RBSAssertion acquireWithError:] + 208
8  AssertionServices              0x30e8 -[BKSAssertion acquire] + 184
9  AssertionServices              0x45e8 -[BKSProcessAssertion acquire] + 756
10 UIKitCore                      0x2158e8 ___addBackgroundTask_block_invoke + 672
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x3a30 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x12c90 _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 56
13 UIKitCore                      0x209dcc _addBackgroundTask + 760
14 UIKitCore                      0x205e34 -[UIApplication _beginBackgroundTaskWithName:expirationHandler:] + 244
15 CoreData                       0x9fb90 +[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator _beginPowerAssertionNamed:withAssert:] + 408
16 CoreData                       0x5be84 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 376
17 CoreData                       0x2e438 -[NSManagedObjectContext save:] + 1512
18 MyApp                           0xac29d4 closure #1 in CoreDataHelper.saveContext(_:completion:) + 91 (CoreDataHelper.swift:91)
19 MyApp                           0x93d96c thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 4350450028 (<compiler-generated>:4350450028)
20 CoreData                       0x1fe18 developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 156
21 libdispatch.dylib              0x3a30 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
22 libdispatch.dylib              0xb124 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 668
23 libdispatch.dylib              0xbc80 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 392
24 libdispatch.dylib              0x16500 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 648
25 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x10bc _pthread_wqthread + 288
26 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xe5c start_wqthread + 8
```

What's causing this and how can this be fixed? Is there an issue with having nested `perform`s?

Answer (score 0):

Nested `perform` calls aren’t necessarily a problem, but it’s important to keep track of which queue you’re using and what code you’re running on that queue. In this case:

- The background context creates its own queue. Any code that the context runs in a `perform` will execute on that queue. This includes the completion handler in your code.
- Your error message suggests that the completion handler is using UIKit somehow, for example to update the UI. UIKit can only run on the main queue,  but letting the background context call the completion handler means it runs on a background queue instead. That’s not allowed and causes crashes.

If you want to update the UI in a completion handler, make sure that the completion code uses `DispatchQueue.main.async` to be sure the code runs on the main queue.

Comment: I'm not updating UI from the completion handler though. The crash is also on the `context.save()` line, there's no indication it's to do with the completion

Comment: Are you using one of `UIApplication`'s background task calls anywhere, like `beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler:)`?

Comment: Nope. From the stack trace it looks like `NSPersistentCoordinator` does this by itself